# Enabled Azure Function's public endpoint when connect to a private endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an azure function defined, with a private endpoint that connects it to my storage subnet.  When the private endpoint is added to the function, it automatically disables public access to the function.  When I go through the UI, I can enable it, but how can I enable this from within a Terraform script or the Azure CLI?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using Azure CLI, I achieved the above requirement.

- Firstly i created Azure function app.
- Added private end point to the function app.
  [image]
- Then, the public access got disabled automatically. So, by using CLI I was able to enable the public access.

> az functionapp show --name ****** --resource-group name

> az resource update --ids /subscriptions/**********************/resourcegroups/resource group name/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/terrafunc --set properties.siteConfig.privateEndpointConnections=[]

[image]

- Access restrictions got enabled in this function app.
  [image]
  [image]